# Phonegap (Cordova) iOS Push Notification onNotificationAPN event triggered in the background

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I use Phonegap 3.0 with [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) plugin to implement iOS Push Notification Service

With node-apn package backend server, I can receive APN message from it.
And registered **onNotificationAPN** function will be triggered in the background and APP icon had a badge count too.

**But** I cannot store the event.payload to localStorage even window Object.

So.. If I wanna get the APN payload data when user revoke app from background (or just click  notification). How can I do?

PS. I registered **resume** event when App initial before backgrounded, and confirmed called when the App revoke.

Sample Code:

```
function onNotificationAPN (event) {
    if ( event.alert )
    {
        navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
    }

    if ( event.sound )
    {
        var snd = new Media(event.sound);
        snd.play();
    }

    if ( event.badge )
    {
        pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, event.badge);
    }

    if ( event.payload )
    {
        localStorage.payload = event.payload   
    }

    // Assign here useless too.
}

document.addEventListener("resume", pushRevoke, false);

function pushRevoke(){
    var payload = localStorage.payload; // undefined
}
```

Comment: would you be able to help me find a link about how to set up PushPlugin for Phonegap 3.0 and newer?  I can only seem to find instructions for older versions of Phonegap.  Thanks

Comment: You could just use --
cordova plugins add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Resolved

Because of PushPlugin JSON Parser Error

In ios / PushPlugin.m Line 171

```
[jsonStr appendFormat:@"foreground:'%d',", 0];
```

Should be

```
[jsonStr appendFormat:@"foreground:'%d'", 0];
```

[Github Issue](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/88)

Comment: hi are you able to get notifications while the app is in the foreground? our app crashes if the app is in the foreground, works fine if it's in the background when notifications come in.

Comment: Does any exception for this issue?

Comment: This is fixed in most recent verstion is now [jsonStr appendFormat:@"foreground:\"%d\"", 0];